Free online editions of tosefot Shantz and other tosefot collections
I'm looking for a way to access a free online scan of the full tosefot shantz. I know that Hebrewbooks has scans of it on עבודה זרה ,מכות, and בכורות, but I am looking right now for חולין and secondarily נזיר, and can't find it anywhere. I also know that some masechtot of Oz Vehadar print it in the back either in full or abbreviated, but I don't have access to a good library or sefarim store at the moment.
More generally I am looking for a reliable way to find editions (preferably accessible freely online) of tosefot collections outside the ones included in the vilna and the smattering of masechtot on hebrewbooks. In particular  תוספות שאנץ ,תוספות איוורא ,תוספות רבינו פרץ, תוספות רא"ש .
If the only option is looking at on manuscripts on ktiv, I could use some help finding what manuscripts to look at and navigating them!

Are you looking specifically for free resources? Otzar HaHochma has all these, but it's not free.

I am looking for free, but thank you for pointing me to that as well

The one for Chullin was printed in שיטת הקדמונים. Try looking for that.
